# C# bouncy castle generate rsa client/server rsa key pair

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle

I have an intermediate private key and certificate and I need to generate client/server key pair and certificate. 
All I found was just generating of a self signed key pairs like this

```
        var r = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        r.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 1024));
        var keys = r.GenerateKeyPair();
```

Is there a way to generate these keys from intermediate private key?

Answer (score 1):

Certificates have chain of trust (https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO16297) but not keys.